# Fetching value of "accept-ranges" via libcurl

Tags: libcurl

I want to fetch the value of accept-ranges" via libcurl [to check the server support for the same. ]

Am thinking to perform with option CURLOPT_NOBODY and parse the response for accept-ranges.
is there any dirct get_info flag to fetch just the accept-ranges values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Accept-Ranges" is a usual HTTP header. You can retrieve headers in a [header function](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html).